# svg animating a semi-circle path

Tags: animation, svg

i am trying to make a donut chart and i wanted to animate the semi-circle path when the values change but the transform of the 'd' path doesnt look 'natural'. Here is what i got so far:

```
<svg height="400" width="400" style="background: #fff">
  <g transform="translate(200,200), scale(75)" stroke-width="0.01" stroke="white">
    <path d="M 1 0 L 2 0 A 2 2 0 0 1 -1.03903 -0.166952 L -0.519515 -0.0834762 A 1 1 0 0 0 1 0" stroke-width="0.01" stroke="black" fill="green">
      <animate attributeName="d" from="M 1 0 L 2 0 A 2 2 0 1 1 0.10467191248588789 -1.9972590695091477 L 0.052335956242943946 -0.9986295347545738 A 1 1 0 1 0 1 0" to="M 1 0 L 2 0 A 2 2 0 0 1 -1.7492394142787915 0.9696192404926743 L -0.8746197071393957 0.48480962024633717 A 1 1 0 0 0 1 0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

i created a jsfiddle to see it live, the transform looks just horrible :)

http://jsfiddle.net/zm03d6La/

I hope there is a way to animate it like after a path so the animation looks like the circle continues to grow or get smaller but not move in wierd directions when it animates.
Thanks in advance, Daniel.

Comment: You need to draw the arcs such that the large arc and sweep flags do not change during animation. Firefox refuses such animations precisely because they don't work sensibly.

Comment: can i create like an animation path of a circle so the animation goes after that path ?

Comment: Even if you avoid sudden jumps from the arc flags, you won't get the animation you want.  When you animate `d` attributes, the points transition in straight lines.  You really have to use JavaScript to get the points to animate along the curve of the arc.  There are plenty of examples available for d3, you could take a look at their source code and adapt it.

Comment: i didnt want to rely on 3rd party libs, i saw that you can animate by using a pathing which can be a curve aswell but i have no idea how to morph by using a pathing circle

Comment: [You may find this example useful.](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/pwEdH)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Live demo.](http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/pwEdH/)  Simply adjust the path as needed.

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 500; }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 800 500" xml:space="preserve">
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:green;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="50" d="M98,127c0,0,1.614,107.653,92,116s108-116,108-116" class="path"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks.. If you like that, you may also get a kick out of this [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/upjDy) on how to draw a circle that appears to be drawn by hand at random.